# When to write to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

When should NSUserDefault values be written? I have a number of default values that could change throughout the duration of the program. Should I be writing the default values immediately after they change or should I wait till the end, when the application is terminated, to write the default values back?

Comment: It somewhat depends on what (and how much) data is in those defaults.  Is it a lot of data (normally, it won't be)?  What's the consequence (and likelihood) that the app crashes before you get a chance to write to NSUserDefaults?  Also, you might want to clarify what you mean by "write".  Are you asking about calling `setObject:forKey:`, or actually persisting the data with a call to `synchronize`?

Comment: Amount of data:2-3 relatively small array (less than 10 objects), 5 or so ints/booleans. I'm not expecting the app to crash (unless its a programming error). I'm asking about calling setObject:forKey:

Comment: user1802143 You never *expect* a production version of the app to crash. Sometimes it happens anyway. @Nate brings up some good points, especially re: severity. If not saving the value causes the user's bank balance to change, that's a problem. If it means they have to reset the time on a clock, maybe not so much.

Comment: Severity is low. At most, the user will just have to reset the settings or add some extra information.

Answer (score 1):

Set the new values to NSUserDefaults directly after the value has changed. NSUserDefaults keeps its data in memory. So writing will most likely be fast enough.

Just make sure that you don't call `synchronize` manually. `synchronize` will write the saved defaults to disk, so this will be relatively slow.
The system will call `synchronize` from time to time, for example when the app goes into the background.

Comment: But be careful that you *do* call synchronize before the app is closed, otherwise none of your changes will save.

Comment: Let's have a look at Apples documentation. [`synchronized`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/synchronize): "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."

Comment: "if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit)" That's what I meant. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, since we don't know when those "periodic intervals" will occur, you have to be sure to call it before the application exits, right? (If I'm misunderstanding please do correct me; that means I've been doing this wrong.)

Comment: Synchronize is for example called when you send the app to the background, e.g. by pressing the home button. To see this in action add a symbolic breakpoint for `-[NSUserDefaults synchronize]` to your project and press the home button.